# Google Charts column colouring?

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts, google-visualization

How can I change the colors of the two columns of google's material column chart?

This is my code for options:

```
var options = {
        chart: {
            title: 'Event Posting',
            subtitle: 'Kairos event posting and student registration',
            colors: ['#b0120a', '#ffab91'],
        }
    };
```

The colors attribute does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the colors are working to me, but why is your options array options.chart? It looks like the colors attribute should be a root of your options, for example:

```js
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawMaterial);

function drawMaterial() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('timeofday', 'Time of Day');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Motivation Level');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Energy Level');

      data.addRows([
        [{v: [8, 0, 0], f: '8 am'}, 1, .25],
        [{v: [9, 0, 0], f: '9 am'}, 2, .5],
        [{v: [10, 0, 0], f:'10 am'}, 3, 1],
        [{v: [11, 0, 0], f: '11 am'}, 4, 2.25],
        [{v: [12, 0, 0], f: '12 pm'}, 5, 2.25],
        [{v: [13, 0, 0], f: '1 pm'}, 6, 3],
        [{v: [14, 0, 0], f: '2 pm'}, 7, 4],
        [{v: [15, 0, 0], f: '3 pm'}, 8, 5.25],
        [{v: [16, 0, 0], f: '4 pm'}, 9, 7.5],
        [{v: [17, 0, 0], f: '5 pm'}, 10, 10],
      ]);

      var options = {
        title: 'Motivation and Energy Level Throughout the Day',
        hAxis: {
          title: 'Time of Day',
          format: 'h:mm a',
          viewWindow: {
            min: [7, 30, 0],
            max: [17, 30, 0]
          }
        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'Rating (scale of 1-10)'
        },
        colors: [
         '#00f',
          '#ff0'
        ]
      };

      var materialChart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      materialChart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: that's correct, `colors` should be at the root and not contained with `chart` -- also, the following static method should be used with _Material_ charts to ensure options work properly --> `google.charts.Bar.convertOptions`